# why does my <br> not work ?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am returning a PHP array back to a JQuery call for appending into a div called "name-data". I want my array to be listed vertically, so I concatenate a br tag in the PHP however, when it gets to the HTML page the br is not being rendered, it just comes out as text. I have tried the various forms of br all without luck.

I am new to JQuery - What am I doing wrong ?  Many Thanks !

**PHP:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName FROM customer limit 5");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo $row['FirstName']."<br />";
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
var name = $('input#name').val();
if($.trim(name) !=''){
    $.post('search.php',{name:name}, function(data){
    $('div#name-data').text(data);
    });
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
Name:<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" id="name-submit" value="grab">
<div id="name-data"> </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `.text()` with `.html()`.

```
$('div#name-data').html(data);
```

Also, for the love of Cthulhu, [parameterize your MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). That's a SQL injection just waiting to happen.

Comment: Many Thanks !! This is not production. I'm learning JQuery however your advice is well taken !

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
 $('div#name-data').text(data);
```

to

```
$('div#name-data').html(data);
```

Read about [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the `<br>` is the last thing in the div, most browsers won't actually render a break.  You need something after it, like this: `<br>&nbsp;`

Comment: No, that's not the reason. The OP is using .text() which only sets the text, it does *not* insert HTML.

Comment: Hence the word "also." Even if OP uses `.html()` instead of `.text()`, this is another likely problem in most browsers.